# MongoDB , how to choose the right design?

Tags: mongodb

I have to create a collection of document and I have a doubt about the right design.

Each document is an "identity"; each Identity has a list of "partner Data"; each partner data are defined by an ID and a set of Data.

One approach can be (1):

```
{
    _id: ...
    partners: [
        {
            id: partner1,
            data: {
                
            }
        },
        {
            id: partner2,
            data: {
                
            }
        },

    ]
}
```

Another approach can be (2)

```
{
    _id: ...
    partners: {
        partner1:  {
            data: {
                
            }
        },
        partner2: {
            data: {
                
            }
        },

    ]
}
```

I prefer the first one, but considering that I could have million of these identities, which could be the most performed schema?

A typical query can be: "how many identities have partner with ID N".

With the second example, a query can be:

```
db.identities.find({partner.partnerName: {$exists:true}})
```

With first approach, how can I get this count?
The second solution is more easy to handle Server Side; each document will have a list where each KEY is the partner ID, so instead of scan all document, I can simply get partner data by key...

What do you think about these solutions? I prefer the first one but the second I think that is more "usable"...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I prefer the first one, but considering that I could have million of these identities, wich could be the most performed schema?

If you going to have millions of identities, then both approaches 
are not really scalable .

Each document in mongo has a size limit (16MB) ([read about it here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents))

In case you are going to have really lot's of identities , 
the scalable approach would be to create a different collection,
only for the relations and partnership data.

Now , I also want you to consider how you treat "partnership",
if I'm a user and I got you on my partners list , will you see me as a partner on your list ?

In case we both see each other as partners , then mongo-db may not be the best solution. graph db's are more appropriate for dealing with relations of this type.

All solutions within mongo for two-ways relations will be built on double updates (Your id on my partner's list , My id on your partner's list). 
(In SQL you could add an extra condition for joining but not in mongo) ,
so you don't need to save twice partnerships . (me and you , you and me)
just you and me.

Do you see where is going this way ?

If you need to go only in one way,
Then just create a second collection , "partnerships" ,

```
{
  _id: should be uniqe,
  user_id: 'your_id',
  partner_id: 'his_id'
  data: {} or just flatten the fields into the root object.
}
```

Please notice that you create a row for each partnership !

Then you could use $lookup in order to query for a user with all of his
partners .

something like:

```
db.getCollection('partners').aggregate([
  {
      $lookup: {
         from: 'parterships',
         localField: '_id',
         foreignField: 'user_id',
         as: 'partners'
      }
  },
  {
      $project: {
        name: 1,
        partners: 1,
        num_partners: { $size: "$partners" }
   }
  }
])
```

Read more about the aggregation stages [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/).

In case you are not going to have lot's of partnership's Then please continue with
your first approach which is good .

The second approach will make most queries to this collection pretty weird and you will always have to write code in order to query this table .
It won't be "straight forward" mongo queries .